# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist. Tried numerous different things already

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I know this is a common issue apparently, but I've gone through a bunch of examples and can't find a solution.

I'm doing the tutorial of django1.8. so I'm not sure if this is a glitch or not. I've tried moving my template file to multiple locations, but so far nothing has worked.

I have my project structured in this way: my project is called "forumtest" and it's inside a virtualenv called "venv". Forumtest has one app called "polls". I had the "templates" folder stored inside the root directory of "forumtest", but I just moved it inside the "polls" directory. However, I got the same result.

As of now, my settings.py file looks like this:

```
"""
Django settings for forumtest project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$nnwkm0ln!$77m1n!%wv-5)k_rhs=-p-)xr-c-+m985w3jq#*='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'forumtest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR,'C:/Desktop/Users/Owner/forumtest/polls/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'forumtest.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'forumtest',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'aldotheapache12',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The 'DIRS' section which looks like this:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR,'C:/Desktop/Users/Owner/forumtest/polls/templates')],
```

Previously looked like this:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

My views file, stored under the "forumtest" directory looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from polls.models import Choice,Question

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions"""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request,question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError,Choice.DoesNotExist):
        #redisplay the question voting form
        return render(request,'polls/detail.html',{
            'question':p,
            'error_message': "you didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

I have the exact same views file under "polls", except with this line (I'm aware that this may be an issue:

```
from .models import Choice,Question
```

Please let me know how I can solve this. Thanks guys!

EDIT: as per requested by @Chris McGinlay, here's the template loader post-mortem:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\forumtest\templates\index.html, polls\question_list.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html, polls\question_list.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html, polls\question_list.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\forumtest\polls\templates\index.html, polls\question_list.html (File does not exist)
```

Thanks for all your comments, guys!

EDIT: So I deleted the extra views file located under the 'forumtest/forumtest' directory, and now I'm getting an error that says

```
cannot import name 'views'
```

:(

EDIT: @Alasdair here's the root urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls',namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Does that "cannot import name 'views'" error occur in the root urls.py? I suspect it does, because you have `from . import views`. The dot means to import from the same directory as the urls.py file, but if you look you will find that your views.py file is not in that directory, it is (or should be) in polls/views.py, so you should use `from polls import views` in the root urls.py.  The `from . import views` command would be what you'd put in polls/urls.py.

Comment: @Chris McGinlay I did that and now I'm getting an error that says, "TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/" and below that it lists "index.html, polls/question_list.html". I just realized I don't have those html files, so it's calling files that actually aren't there haha. I'll create them and see if that fixes the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the templates DIRS in the TEMPLATES setting should be as it was:

`'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR,'templates')],`

Having `'APP_DIRS': True,` should pull in the templates from all your apps.

When you obtain the dreaded 'TemplateDoesNotExist at ...' message in your browser, it will probably help to look down to the Template Loader post-mortem:

**Django tried loading these templates, in this order:**

Hopefully that will give some clues - could you post it here?

Comment: +1 The 'Django tried loading these templates, in this order' should contain the required information to solve the problem.

Comment: @ChrisMcGinlay I changed the 'DIRS' to have just 'templates. Gere

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to include the polls directory in your `DIRS` setting. Django will find it because you have `APP_DIRS` set to `True`.

So you can change `DIRS` back to.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

Now, note that there should be a `polls` directory inside `polls/templates` for example the details template should be at `polls/templates/polls/details.html`.

Finally, stick with the tutorial, and keep the polls views in `polls/views.py`. Having two similar files `forumtest/views.py` and `polls/views.py` is going to make things very confusing.

Comment: I already have a polls directory in the 'polls/templates' file. Yeah I agree with you about the views, as soon as I noticed it I could feel problems inbound. Problem is the tutorial wasn't exactly clear about placing the views files :(

Comment: To solve the import error, please show your root urls.py. Note that you should have `template_name = 'polls/index.html'` to be consistent with your other views.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, open that file in finder or outside the text editor/IDE and rename it, also check the extension.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'polls',
)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
```

with this your templates should be inside "polls/templates" directory or in the main "templates" directory

Comment: These are the old template settings. The OP is using Django 1.8, which has a new `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: I am using it in django 1.8.4 without any issues. You can at least try this to see if the issue is fixed then next step would be to migrate towards new configuration.

Comment: Yes, you can use the old settings in 1.8, but you should not mix the new and old settings. Since the OP is already using `TEMPLATES`, they don't gain anything by switching to the old settings.

Comment: i agree. Try this: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,   -> this goes inside TEMPLATES as indicated by Alasdair :)

Comment: @Chris McGinlay I changed the 'DIRS' section like you said. I'll include the Loader post-mortem in an edit of my original post.